# Macro define issue for g++ in cygwin

Tags: g++, cygwin, gnu-make

I create a make project in cygwin.

```
src = $(shell ls | grep .cpp)
obj = $(src:%.cpp=%.o)

$(page_timeout): $(obj)
   $(cc) -o -D BUILD_TYPE $(page_timeout) $(obj)

$(synchronize): $(obj)
   $(cc) -o -DBUILD_TYPE=2 $(synchronize) $(obj)
```

you can find out that i tried 2 from of macro define in makefile. But neither of them work. It means g++ did not know BUILD_TYPE in complying.

Comment: What is BUILD_TYPE supposed to be ? Where are defined `page_timeout` and `synchronize` ? You are missing  to define the output file immediately after `-o`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I define Build_type by config CXXFLAGS for c++ before compile.

Details in main make file.

```
$(page_timeout):
    $(MAKE) clean
    $(MAKE) -f make_page.mk objs
    $(cc) -o $(page_timeout) $(obj)

$(inquiry):
    $(MAKE) clean
    $(MAKE) -f make_inquiry.mk objs
    $(cc) -o $(inquiry) $(obj)

$(synchronize): 
    $(MAKE) clean
    $(MAKE) -f make_sync.mk objs
    $(cc) -o $(synchronize) $(obj)
```

Details in make_page.mk

```
 cc = g++
    deps = $(shell ls  | grep .h)
    src = $(shell  ls | grep .cpp)
    obj = $(src:%.cpp=%.o) 

#%.o: %.c $(deps)
#   $(cc) -c  $  -DBUILD_TYPE=1 $@



CXXFLAGS += -DBUILD_TYPE=0

objs: $(obj)
    echo "Pagetimeout build complete"
```